# Grohe single handle kitchen faucet leak. Do I need to replace entire facet?

Tags: repair, leak, kitchen-sink

My Grohe single handle kitchen faucet is leaking. Water is coming to underneath.

Is there anyway to fix this by myself?

Can I fix this by replacing cartridge? 
Or should I replace entire facet?

Could you give me your advice?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What do you mean by "because water comes through all hoses"?

Comment: I mean I think leakage happens at the neck of facet because water comes along from all 4 hoses. All 4 hoses are wet.

Comment: How long has this Grohe faucet been in service? Do you have the use and installation instructions? This is a premium faucet; I would assume that is can be repaired rather than replaced.  My first impulse  would be to replace the cartridge.  But it is not clear to me where it is leaking. Are any of the hose connections at the base redoable or are they permanent factory crimp connections. Is it only leaking when the main on-off hot-cold valve is open? Or is it leaking when the main valve is closed?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'm not sure neither but it seems mixing valve. I'll try to replace cartridge because I don't know how to take is apart and check inside...

Comment: BTW my faucet is 4 years old.